# An issue lies in the rendering of the title element when the website is displayed in Persian

Tags: wordpress

I have a multilingual website. When I open home page in English language it shows normal as following image
[Linkable images when website is selected in English language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cVaF.png)
But once I change it to persian, the linkable title of this image change and it shows anchor element instead of the title as following image.
[Linkable images when website is selected in Persian language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AKXy.png)
the link to the page is [here](https://digital-cso.org/en/)